# Is it bad practice to cite MSc dissertations?

Tags: publications, citations

While searching for references on a certain class of problems I came across a well-written master's dissertation. It did not contain much in terms of new results, but  it did a good job of explaining what happens in the important papers in the field (or so I believe). This was helpful - my interest in that class of problems is that it's adjecent to the problem I'm writting about, so it's important for me for context and historical reasons, but it's not a subject I want to research in much depth; having read the dissertation and a introductions to some of the relevant papers, I feel I know as much as I need to know. I should also mention that some of the relevant papers are in French, so I was very grateful that someone explained in English what their gist is. I also feel that what I read in the published papers is enough to reasonably write all that I need to write in the introduction, but having looked through the dissertaition certainly helped me orient myself.

Now, my dillema is: Should I cite the dissertation? It is not generally seen as a requirement to cite expository materials on a subject, so I don't think I *have* to. But I also feel that it would perhaps be nice to cite it: it acknowledges that I benefited from reading it, and it helps potential readers who might become interested in the subject. If it was a published survey article, I would definitely cite it. On the other hand, this is a piece of writting that didn't go through the usual peer review process, and that was almost by definiton written by a rather inexperienced mathematician. I'm worried including the citation could annoy some readers, and possibly the dissertaion's authour.

What is the best course of action in a case like this?

Comment: No, it is not bad practice. (And no, "might annoy the author" does not count as a reason for skipping a reference, unless perhaps the author explicitly told you to not cite their work and gave a good reason.)

Answer (score 5):

Cite it. It's a source you used, so you need to cite.

In addition, good explanations are also good for readers who are looking for an introduction.

---

> didn't go through the usual peer review process

Where I am, a Master thesis is reviewed (+ graded) by two professors, and that can include a list of required corrections/clarification for the final version. A paper is possibly reviewed by 2 PhD students who have barely published their first paper...

> was almost by definiton written by a rather inexperienced mathematician

so is everyones first paper. Including possibly reviews: I know PhD students who were put to the task of writing a review paper right with their literature study to familiarize them with their thesis subject.

---

There are things in my Diplom thesis that I wouldn't write or do like that any more (now, 15 years later: science and my personal knowledge have advanced, after all - which is as it should be), though the downright mistakes I've found are mostly typos or otherwise the correct expression is clear. So it's rather that I have *different* expressions/sentences/wording now that I think are more clear/better or explain things I could only observe back then.
But then, the same is true for some of my (peer-reviewed) papers.